java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: at runtime for gosu join query for two tables
I am trying to use this query to get Claim object based on join with message table and some filter criteria as below.
Query is to get all claim objects from Claim table join with Message table on claim.id = message.claim where message.Destinationid =66 and Message.ErrorDescription="errordescription"
var claims = Query.make(Claim).join(Message#Claim).compare(Message#DestinationID, Relop.Equals, 66).compare(Message#ErrorDescription, Relop.Equals, "errordescription").select()
I am getting this error at runtime.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value gw.lang.reflect.features.PropertyReference@563f761c (type gw.lang.reflect.features.PropertyReference)  is not compatible with property entity.Message.ID (gw.pl.persistence.core.Key)
What am I doing wrong here?
